# What is the way to do pagging in jsp with hibernate?

Tags: java, jsp, pagination

On JSP page I can't get the number of pages for data. I can get data of predefined page size that if I want first 7 data, or second 7 data I can get it. But I'm not able to identify number of pages. What is the best way to do pagging in JSP?

Comment: execute a request to get the total number of elements returned by the request: select count(...) from ... where ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call a method to return the total count of all rows in your dataset then use this or something similar

```
int numberOfPages = (totalRecords / pageSize);

if (totalRecords % pageSize != 0) {
   numberOfPages++;
}
```

Comment: so this means every time I refresh page or change page I have to calculate this everytime.

Comment: Not personally, but yes this will need to be calculated. What if your query returned more data because someone added a new row?